# Writing a word document in Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to write the output Strings into a word document using the following code :

```
 try {
          out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("report.doc", true)));
          out.println("<html><style>"+string1+"</style><table cellspacing = 0 cellpadding = 0><tr>" + string2 + "</html>" +  (char)12);
      } catch (IOException e) {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "File error " + e.getMessage());
      } finally {
          if (out != null) {
              try {
                  out.close();
              } catch (Exception ignore) {
              }
          }
      }
```

If this method is called (let's say) 10 times, it only writes the information of the first String. However, when I replace  'report.doc'  with 'report.html', the created html file contains all the information of the 10 Strings.

How can I alter my code so that it can generate a word document with  all the information as is the created html document?

Comment: check apache poi library -> http://poi.apache.org/

Comment: Could it be because you have html-tags each time, and the document only should contain one?

Comment: When you say "it only writes the information of the first String", do you mean that you only see the first string in Word when you open the document? Or does the file actually only contain the first string?

Comment: What I see in the document is a single String instead of 10. When I drag the word document into notepad, all the Strings are present.

Comment: A `.doc` file is not a text file with a funny extension.  It's a structured binary data format with a lot of fancy stuff in it.  To do this properly, you'll need a library to actually create that format for you.

Comment: Thank you very much guys. I solved the problem by including only one html tag in the whole document as suggested by Matsemann.

Comment: You need to use API that can create word document, word document is not just made of strings, use the library suggested by @npocmaka. HTML can be constructed from strings, so when you create html you see all the strings, I was also curious to know how are you calling this code 10 times ?

Comment: Making a .rtf file should be easier, and those can be opened in Word too. http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a .doc processor java library. Without the help of word processor library, you need to know the format of .doc documents, just you know the structure of .html documents.

[Apache poi](http://poi.apache.org/) is a good example of such a library.

Another approach is to port the MS Office libraries to a java library using COM bridges. I have been using a commercial tool for that purpose. [JACOB](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/) seems an open source example of a Java-COM bridge, though I have not tested this product.